# When i export csv, my column value is automatically changes in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, csv

i have used following python code.

```
time = ['09-11', '11-13', '14-16']

for tm in time:
    data2['session_time'] = tm
    data2.to_csv("./DATA/COA111/demo.csv")
```

here is image file of my csv output.

[image]

when i'm exporting csv i need session_time column record like 09-11 but instead of this it will shows me 11-Sep.

I don't know how this automatically converts the value of session_time column.

Comment: This has nothing to do both with `pandas` or `csv`, but Excel interpreting your data type and guessing what it should be. If you open the raw csv, you will see that it's exported correctly. The downside of csv is that it does not store metadata on your column types for example. This should be posted as an excel question.

Comment: As per your suggestion i have tried to export as excel & problem is solved now
Thanks @Erfan